# Some data missing when sent from Paho MQTT to cloud

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am trying to send data of around 500 tags (changing data per second) from Paho MQTT to Cloud. Initially all data is received, but after some time it starts losing samples.

- Tried changing "Keep Alive Time"
- Checked on Wireshark to monitor the traffic.

Part of my code

```
def queue_consumer(queue):
    global TestCount

    global responseList
    while True:
        TestCount=0
        for items in range(0, queue.qsize()):
            responseList.append(queue.get_nowait())
            queue.task_done()
        item1="topicName"
        if item1 is None:
            print("BREAKKK")
            break
        else:
            mqttmessage1 = json.dumps(responseList)
            objClient = ConnectionClient()
            objClient.client.publish("topicName", mqttmessage1 , qos=1)
            responseList=[]
            del objClient
        time.sleep(1)           # time after which the next items in queue
                                # would be processed for publishing
```

I expect all data to be published to the cloud with timestamp.

Comment: Please take care when pasting in Python code. Indentation is very important when reading Python. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if your `ConnectionClient()` opens and closes a connection for each time around the main loop. However, it looks like you close the connection each time (via the `del objClient`). If so, I suggest you create an `mqtt.Client` on startup and connect to the service. Then each time you run your main loop send the messages and do not close the connection until your program exits.

You might also check that the service provider is not applying some limits. 500 topics every second seems like quite a lot unless you are paying for the service.

Comment: It is not 500 topics .Its one topic onlqy which is sending mqtt message of size around 27k-28k. per second for 500 tags.mqtt message looks like  [{"values": {"tag1": 118.0}, "ts": 1562749540425}, {"values": {"tag2": 118.0}, "ts": 1562749540425}, {"values": {"tag3": 118.0}, "ts": 156274954}....]